# How was Lewis not recognized in 'Meet the Robinsons'?

Tags: meet-the-robinsons

In the animated family film "Meet the Robinsons" young inventor Lewis finds himself whisked away to a Jetsons-like future which was all made possible by the inventions of genius Cornelius Robinson. He meets the eccentric extended family of Robinson, including the inventor's parents Bud & Lucille. By the end of the film, Lewis finds out that Cornelius is actually

> a grown version of himself, having been adopted by Bud and Lucille, with Cornelius being a nickname given by Bud.

Bud has issues with his memory, but Lucille doesn't seem to. **With this in mind, how was Lewis not recognized by either one?**

*Note: Sorry - there's really no way to ask this question without spoilers...*

Answer (score 3):

They aren't accustomed to time travel.  It had recently been invented, he just finished his second functional prototype. 
When you see a kid that looks like someone you knew 30 years ago, your brain knows it is not them, especially when you watched them grow up into a man. They also adopt him at 12, just ready to start puberty, they really don't have the child version of him very long.  Frannie was also in the picture when he was 12 and has known him at least as long as Bud and Lucille, maybe longer, and she doesn't figure it out right away either.

But in the end, they all recognize him once the hat is off.